# Merge dataframe rows when values are NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to flatten a dataframe as in the example below.

I have the next dataframe:

```
    file name   format  location
0   movie1.mp4  NaN     NaN
1   NaN         NaN     D:/mymovies
2   NaN         mp4     NaN
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
    file name   format  location
0   movie1.mp4  mp4 D:/mymovies
```

Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use forward filling for first column, if first non missing value is first value of group and then aggregate with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first non missing value per groups:

```
df = df.groupby(df['file name'].ffill()).first().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    file name format     location
0  movie1.mp4    mp4  D:/mymovies
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['file name'].ffill())
0    movie1.mp4
1    movie1.mp4
2    movie1.mp4
Name: file name, dtype: object
```

If first column is index:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.to_series().ffill()).first().reset_index()
print (df)
    file name format     location
0  movie1.mp4    mp4  D:/mymovies
```

Comment: @OvidiuDiaconu - You are welcome. Please test if values in `file name` are first per groups for correct output. If not, please create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).